# Unwrapped property in C# JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I need to deserialize this JSON:

```
{ "user_id": 0, "resource_id": 0, "resource_name": "file.xml" ...}
```

To this class:

```
public class Resource 
{
    public ResourceId ResourceId { get; set; }
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
    ... 
}

public class ResourceId 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
}
```

I need the deserializer to create a new ResourceId object to store the values of "resource_id" and "user_id". Also, I need to serialize the object back. Is that possible?

I'm using JSON.net deserializer/serializer.

Comment: well, as I see it right now, the JSON data just has 3 values contained in an RootObject... But I'm not that experienced with JSON data, and I just special pasted that JSON data in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your `ResourceId` class won't even compile because [member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdhfk2xk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  Instead, you must do something like:

```
public class ResourceId 
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Your next problem is that the properties of your contained class `ResourceId` are appearing in the JSON as properties of the container class `Resource`.  One way to deal with this *without changing your data model* is to serialize them as *private* properties on the container class that proxy the properties of the underlying `ResourceId`.  This can be done by annotating `Resource` with [data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class Resource 
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public ResourceId ResourceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name="user_id")]
    private int? user_id {
        get
        {
            return ResourceId == null ? (int ?)null : ResourceId.UserId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ResourceId = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ResourceId == null)
                    ResourceId = new ResourceId();
                ResourceId.UserId = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name="resource_id")]
    private int? resource_id
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceId == null ? (int?)null : ResourceId.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ResourceId = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ResourceId == null)
                    ResourceId = new ResourceId();
                ResourceId.Id = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name="resource_name")]
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
}
```

Or with Json.NET's [`[JsonIgnore]` and `[JsonProperty]` serialization attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) like so:

```
public class Resource 
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ResourceId ResourceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    private int? user_id {
        get
        {
            return ResourceId == null ? (int ?)null : ResourceId.UserId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ResourceId = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ResourceId == null)
                    ResourceId = new ResourceId();
                ResourceId.UserId = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("resource_id")]
    private int? resource_id
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceId == null ? (int?)null : ResourceId.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ResourceId = null;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ResourceId == null)
                    ResourceId = new ResourceId();
                ResourceId.Id = value.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("resource_name")]
    public string ResourceName { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- The properties should be private because it really doesn't make sense to change them individually when `null` is a possible value.  For instance doing:

  ```
  resource.user_id = null;
  resource.resource_id = 3;
  ```

  might produce unexpected results.
- Using the data contract attributes makes the class compatible with the data contract serializers, which might be useful.

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SuSXJo) for data contract attributes and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gQ8cMm) for Newtonsoft attributes.